# Using For Loop and Foreach to create a list in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a draft order for a game I'm working on but I cannot get it to function how I need it to. I need 5 rounds with each round number properly and each pick should be numbered 1-10 for each round. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
List<Draft> _draftorder = new List<Draft>();

foreach (Team t in teams)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        _draftorder.Add(new Draft()
        {
            city = t.city,
            round = i++,
            pick = i++,
        });
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: each `i++` increases the value stored in `i`, so you are adding 1 to it three times within the `for` loop

Comment: So `Round` and `Pick` should always be the same per `Draft` object?

Comment: So I need a second for loop for the "picks"?

Comment: @RobertCole it would be much easier if you gave us a sample output, instead of us trying to guess

Comment: @maccettura Round should be 1-5 (each team has a 1-5) and Pick should be 1-10 for each round.

Comment: Team - Rd - Pick
Team1  - 1 - 1
Team2 - 1- 2
...
Team1 - 2 - 1
Team 2 - 2 - 2
...

Comment: If you want, for a single round, 10 `Draft` objects with `round` value 1, and each with different `pick` value (1 through 10), then yes, you will need another loop, the outer `for` loop being used for `round`, and the inner `for` loop used for `pick`

Comment: Why would your Draft list not include the team?

Comment: Dont you want these draft orders to be randomized or something? Seems like you should generate all draft picks first, then assign a team to them based on whatever your "random" criteria would be

Comment: The teams are generated randomly currently, later on I plan to make sure it goes in a correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the logic is easier to follow when the code matches the stepwise workflow of the requirements, and the variable names match the concepts in the requirements.

```
List<Draft> _draftorder = new List<Draft>();

for (int currentRound=1; currentRound<=10; currentRound++)
{
    int pickOrder = 1;
    foreach (Team t in teams)
    {
        _draftorder.Add(new Draft()
        {
            city = t.city,
            round = currentRound,
            pick = pickOrder++
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: He changed his requirement: _Now I need to find a way to randomly assign a different pick number to each team instead of it counting up to 5._

Comment: Not the way I read it. I understand it to mean each round has its own namespace with respect to pick, between 1 and 10 each round. I'm assuming there are ten teams.

Comment: @JohnWu yeah I just re-read the question.  I swear it was different at some point.  Idk

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional `for` loop and put the `foreach` loop inside the first `for` loop:

```
List<Draft> _draftorder = new List<Draft>();

// Allow 5 rounds
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    // Allow every team to pick some drafts
    foreach (Team t in teams)
    {
        // Limit them to a specific amount of picks per round
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            _draftorder.Add(new Draft()
            {
                city = t.city,
                round = i,
                pick = j,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped but its not doing exactly what I need. I was able to change round = i++ to get 5 picks for each team. I also changed j <= 10 to 5 so that teams don't get too many picks. Now I need to find a way to randomly assign a different pick number to each team instead of it counting up to 5.

Comment: @RobertCole Stick to the original question, which did not mention anything about "random" picks.

Comment: Actually, I said that I need picks numbered 1-10. Each team must have the same number pick per round. If I left that detail out then my bad. But I did say each round should be numbered 1-10.

Comment: @RobertCole, I updated my answer based on your comments